# How to create different voice effects in android?

Tags: android-studio, audio-recording, android-library, voice-recognition, voice-recording

I'm developing Voice Changer App who record the user voice and create different effects.

I'm using AudioRecord to record the voice and save in the .pcm format using BufferedInputStream.
And using AudioTrack I play the audio. 
By changing the playbackrate in AudioTrack object it is also creating some effects. 
But these effects are not enough for my app. 
I need to generate some advance effects like audio play as Fan, Alien, Death.

Inspirational App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baviux.voicechanger

PlayBackRates which I'm passing in AudioTrack object.

```
Integer[] freqset = {11025,     //  Normal,
                        16000,      //  Chipmunk
                        22050,      //  Bee
                        6050,       //  Slow Motion
                        17640,        //  Ghost
                       // 41000,      //  Funny
                        30000,      //  Elephent
                        8000,       //  Robot
                        10500,      //  Motor Bike
                        //35005,      //  Pikachu
                        25500,      //  Minion
                        15655,       //  Old Lady
                        52920,
                        12000,
                      32000
    };
```

What I need to do to create more voice effects ?

Thanks in advance